Is it true that $I + X^2 - (X - Y)(I + Y^2)^{-1} (X- Y) \succ 0$?
Let $X, Y$ be two real symmetric positive definite matrices.
Is it true that
$$
I + X^2 - (X - Y)(I + Y^2)^{-1} (X- Y) \succ 0?
$$
For instance if $x, y \geq 0$ are scalars, this inequality is the same as
$$
(1+x^2)(1+y^2) - (x-y)^2 = (xy + 1)^2 > 0, 
$$
which is evidently true.
This immediately implies that if $X$ and $Y$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, then this holds.
Question: Suppose $X, Y \succeq 0$ are not necessarily simultaneously diagonalizable. Then does it hold that $I + X^2 - (X - Y)(I + Y^2)^{-1} (X- Y) \succ 0$?

Denote the sum in question by $S$. It is the Schur complement of $I+Y^2$ in
$$
A=\pmatrix{I+X^2&X-Y\\ X-Y&I+Y^2}=\pmatrix{X&-I\\ I&Y}\pmatrix{X&I\\ -I&Y}=:B^TB.
$$
Since $\det(B)=\det(XY+I)=\det(X^{1/2}YX^{1/2}+I)>0$, $A$ is positive definite. As $I+Y^2$ is also positive definite, its Schur complement in $A$, i.e., $S$, is positive definite.
